# How to stop the ftp connection if the server is not avaliable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ftp

I create an inputstream for ftp request as below:

```
ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);

networkStream = (NSInputStream *) ftpStream;        

[self.networkStream read:<#(uint8_t *)#> maxLength:<#(NSUInteger)#>]
```

when I read data, if the server is not able to be connected, the programme will be stucked at the third line above. Is there a method could stop the connection after some second which you can define? Or if some other method to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a synchronous `read`. Instead, set a delegate on the stream object, schedule it on the run loop, and call `-open`. If you're on the main thread of an app, just return control back to the framework at this point and it will run the run loop for you. If you're on a background thread or writing a command-line tool, run the thread's run loop yourself. Your delegate will be called when there's data to be read.

To establish a timeout for the connection, you can schedule a timer on the run loop. Alternatively, if you're running the run loop yourself, you can just put a limit on how long you'll run it. If the time expires before the connection has been made, just close the stream.